# How to convert YAML duplicate keys into arrays

Tags: perl, yaml

I have a file that's almost YAML, with the exception of duplicate keys. Is there a existing method to convert duplicate keys into arrays?

My code looks like:

```perl
use Data::Dumper;
use YAML::XS;

local $YAML::XS::ForbidDuplicateKeys = 1;
 
my $x = YAML::XS::Load($yaml_string);
print Dumper $x;
```

Sample input file:

```yaml
info:
    family: skywalker

    person:
        id: 1
        status: active

        details:
            gender: male

            name:
                first: Anakin
                last: Skywalker

        children: Leia
        children: Han Solo

    person:
        id: 58
        status: active

        details:
            gender: female

            name:
                first: Padme
                last: Amidala

        children: Leia
        children: Han Solo
```

Desired input file:

```
info:
    family: skywalker

    person:
    -
        id: 1
        status: active

        details:
            gender: male

            name:
                first: Anakin
                last: Skywalker
        children:
        - Leia
        - Han Solo

    -
        id: 58
        status: active

        details:
            gender: female

            name:
                first: Padme
                last: Amidala
        children:
        - Leia
        - Han Solo
```

Comment: *"Is there an existing method to convert duplicate keys into arrays?"* Seems like that requires a change to the source code, see line 362: https://metacpan.org/release/INGY/YAML-LibYAML-0.88/source/LibYAML/perl_libyaml.c#L362. Maybe add a feature request: https://github.com/ingydotnet/yaml-libyaml-pm/issues ?

Comment: ... or write your own yaml parser using e.g. [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2) and a BNF grammer for yaml, for example https://github.com/darthwalsh/JustAnotherYamlParser, then modify this grammar to handle duplicate keys

Comment: To clarify, also provide expected output in the case the duplicate keys are mismatching types (one key has hash value and another has sequence value), if the duplicates have only sequence values, only hash values, or only scalar values..

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland. In my case, keys with mismatching values should be forbidden. I'll attempt to pre-process the file for now, and look into the options you suggested.

Comment: You can work at the event level, i.e. read in the sequence of events, modify the structure, and write them out again. LibYAML has an API for that and the Perl module wraps LibYAML so you should have access to it but I don't know enough Perl to be able to tell you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification for [YAML mappings](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#mapping) says:

> The content of a *mapping* node is an unordered set of *key/value* node *pairs*, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique.

Your keys are not unique and therefore you do not have a valid YAML (as you already know - "I have a file that's almost YAML"). Therefore, you should not expect to be able to parse that file with a YAML parser.

I guess you would need to write some kind of parser for your "almost YAML" which produces a Perl data structure in the format that you want. You could then use a standard YAML library to convert that data structure to YAML.

Comment: Thank you @DaveCross. I guess I was mislead by `$YAML::XS::ForbidDuplicateKeys` thinking there’s a way to allow it and/or take advantage of the opposite.

Comment: @hq: Did you try turning the option off? It just means you don't get an error - but the parser still ignores the contents of all but one of the duplicate keys.

Comment: Correct. The parser ignores the contents of all but one of the duplicate keys, which is not what I'm looking for. I need the content of all duplicate keys, stored in an array instead. I shall open another question specifically for parsing.